# Execute spring app using mvn exec:java

Tags: java, spring, maven

My maven JAR app consists of two modules - framefowrk and accounting - and an aggregator. The module framework defines some spring classes which are used in the accounting. The accounting
contains a main-Class and the framework as a maven dependency. I run the Main-Class in eclipse via "Run as->Java Application" - all works fine. Now I'm trying to execute that main using

mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="accounting.MyMainClass"

The command produces following output:

```
ava.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jcrSessionFactory' is defined
... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jcrSessionFactory' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1094)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
...
```

Obviously the spring stuff is not known in the accounting. I would like to know where the difference between the "Run as->Java Application" and the mvn exec:java is and how to solve the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there anything in the Run Configuration for this class within Eclipse other than just the reference to this main class?  JVM args, perhaps?

Comment: Check the error messages: `tion: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jcrSessionFactory' is defined
... 6 more`.

Comment: There is no any configuration within the eclipse Run As, all is default/empty. The jcrSessionFactory bean seems also ok: `<bean id="jcrSessionFactory" class="org.springmodules.jcr.JcrSessionFactory">
      <property name="repository" ref="repository" />
   </bean>`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to "mvn install" your framework dependency? Changes there will not have reached Maven but maybe be visible in Eclipse.

The other thing that might go wrong is ordering. How did you load the configuration? If it is order dependent (e.g. using `classpath*:` with duplicate bean names or `classpath:` with duplicate file names on the classpath) then the result might be different.

Comment: Thank you, but the modules are installed cleanly